# webm to mp4 without loosing audio video sync

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, webm

Iam trying to covert webm to mp4 using ffmpeg so that the output file is playable in all browsers.

Iam using this ffmpeg command in ubuntu

```
ffmpeg -i inpput.webm -f mp4 -copyts -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -vf scale="380:-2" -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3 output.mp4
```

It is converting the file to mp4 but that file is out of sync in Mac safari browser and chrome browser. Means the audio and video is not syncing and sometimes the video gets stopped in between and audio goes on.

If I play the input.web media file directly in chrome it is playing perfectly fine, the same input.webm is also playing good with firefox. But the converted mp4 is out of sync in safari on mac and all chrome browsers.

However if the output.mp4 is played on ipad safari it is playing fine.
The Mac safari version I tried is 11.03
iPad safari version is 11.3

Firefox and chrome are all latest.

firefox : 59.0.2(64 bit), 
chrome : 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Please help me out with what Iam doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution?